# How to initialize sockaddr_in using addrinfo

Tags: c++, sockets

```
void ClientCreate(struct addrinfo * addr, 
                  const char* port) {

  sockaddr_in service;

  service.sin_family = AF_INET;

  service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr ;       /* What do I put here? */ 

  service.sin_port = (u_short)atoi(port);
```

I don't have to use `inet_addr()` I know have tried many possibility nothing works.

Also on the port the MSDN example used `htons()` but the above works.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What is wrong with using `htons` aznc `inet_addr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a quick look at [getaddrinfo](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html). This will populate multiple `addrinfo` structures, and return them to you.

A quick example (stolen partially from [Beej](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/getaddrinfoman.html)):

```
int sockfd;  
struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
int rv;

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // use AF_INET6 to force IPv6
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

if ((rv = getaddrinfo("www.example.com", "http", &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
    exit(1);
}
```

If you *really* want to do it manually, be sure to use [htons](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html) ..

Answer (score 2):

> service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(What do I put here?);

It should be ip address of server,

//if server is localhost
`service.sin_addr.s_addr =  inet_addr("127.0.0.1");`.

> Also on the port the MSDN example used htons()

`htons` converts host byte order to network byte order.